# Azure Web Jobs - Fetch Last Run time & Status programatically

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Does Azure SDK provide an option to fetch the last job run time programmatically to check and apply a specific logic based on the time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the api should have that info.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API

List all triggered jobs in swagger format

GET /api/triggeredwebjobsswagger

```
[
  {
    name: "jobName",
    runCommand: "...\run.cmd",
    type: "triggered",
    url: "",
    history_url: "",
    extra_info_url: "",
    latest_run:
      {
        id: "20131103120400",
        status: "Success",
        start_time: "2013-11-08T02:56:00.000000Z",
        end_time: "2013-11-08T02:57:00.000000Z",
        duration: "00:01:00",
        output_url: "",
        error_url: "",
        url: ""
      }
  }
]
```

Comment: I suggest rephrasing this into a complete answer, or leaving this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't an easy way to get that information programmatically. All that information is stored in the storage account that drives the WebJobs Dashboard, but the storage format is tailored for the Dashboard, so might not be easy to consume for your usage.

We have had feature requests for something similar to what you are asking for see [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/623) in our public repo. Feel free to add your scenario details to that issue.